# Do 42% of young muslims in France support suicide bombings?

Tags: religion, islam, terrorism

In this youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avavZKtf6-g), in the minute 2:20, the narrator gives some absurd-sounding statistics. After claiming that "21% of syrian migrants support ISIS", he says that "22% of young muslim migrants living in germany support suicide bombings". This comes along the following image titled "*Muslim Support for Suicide Bombing*":

[image]

Is the data presented reliable?

Comment: None of the claims say "all bombings" or "every bombing".  For example, the first line: 8% said "often justified" or "sometimes justified" and 5% said "rarely justified".  The 13% is the sum of those two; that's what they mean by "net" up there.

Comment: Please remove personal research. That is fine in an answer, but makes your question too specific.

Comment: @Sklivvz Why is this off-topic?

Comment: It's illegal to satistics based on the ethnic (or religious) group of the people polled in France.

Comment: @Gabe12 The source says 42% are those who think it is "ever justified", "ever justified" being a combination of "often/sometimes" and "rarely", whereas the question at the bottom changes this to "all suicide bombings are justified".

Comment: @MakorDal It's only illegal for a census to distinguish based upon beliefs or ethnicity.  Polls or surveys are ok.

Comment: @Gabe12 The exact question people were asked was "Some people think that suicide bombing and other forms of violence against civilian targets are justified in order to defend Islam from its enemies. Other people believe that, no matter what the reason, this kind of violence is never justified. Do you personally feel that this kind of violence is often justified to defend Islam, sometimes justified, rarely justified, or never justified?"  In France, 6% said "often", 10% "sometimes", 19% "rarely", 64% "never".  http://www.pewresearch.org/files/old-assets/pdf/muslim-americans.pdf#page=60

Comment: I've removed the non-notable parts and reopened -- your research and conclusions are not notable and confuse the claim. Feel free to answer the question with the same data if you wish, though.

Answer (score 6):

When [asked in May 2006](http://www.pewresearch.org/files/old-assets/pdf/muslim-americans.pdf#page=60):

> Now, on another subject...Some people think that suicide bombing and other forms of violence against civilian targets are justified in order to defend Islam from its enemies. Other people believe that, no matter what the reason, this kind of violence is never justified. Do you personally feel that this kind of violence is often justified to defend Islam, sometimes justified, rarely justified, or never justified?

Muslims is France responded:

6% "often"

10% "sometimes"

19% "rarely"

64% "never"

For the subset that were 18-29 years old:

19% "often" or "sometimes"

23% "rarely"

57% "never"

All the data in the OP graph match the "ever justified" column of the table "More Support for Suicide Bombing
Among Younger Muslims" which is on page 54 (page 60 of the pdf) of the report [Muslim Americans](http://www.pewresearch.org/files/old-assets/pdf/muslim-americans.pdf#page=60)

Comment: So then if "*support*" means "*not against 100% of the time*", the stats posted by the OP are true? This seems like a good point to put in the answer.

Comment: @LCIII I added something like that to the end of the answer, but the exact wording of the survey question excludes suicide bombing of military targets. Someone might answer "never", but still support the 9/11 attack on the Pentagon, considering it a military target, or the 23 October 1983 suicide bombings or many other suicide bombings.